# Oracle SQL : Select Query : search if clob Contains a string with pattern matching

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Orable Table with one CLOB column which contains JSON data. I need a query which will search within the CLOB data.

I have used the condition `where DBMS_LOB.instr(colName,'apple:')>0` which gives the records having `apple:`. However, I need to the query to return records with any number of apples *other than blank*, meaning, the json `apple` key should have a value.

I am thinking of something like `where DBMS_LOB.instr(colName,'apple:**X**')>0`, where `X` can be any number not null. I tried `regexp_instr` but it seems this is not correct for CLOB.

Are there any alternatives to solve this?

Comment: This is a misue of a relational database. It's perfectly fine to store json data within a db, but if you need to be able to search within that json data you should **really** also extract the fields you care about at insert/update time and give them real columns of their own.

Comment: oracle has built in support for querying json.  read up on that

Comment: ... starting with Oracle 12.1 and improved in further releases.

Comment: If you are storing JSON in the Oracle database, you **must** tell us your Oracle version. Newer versions have very strong support for JSON, while older ones (up to 11.2) don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic string functions for parsing JSON inputs are dangerous - you will get false positives, for example, when something that looks like a JSON object is in fact embedded in a string value. (Illustrated by ID = 101 in my example below.)

The ideal scenario is that you are using Oracle 19 or higher; in that case you can use a simple call to `json_exists` as illustrated below. In the sample table I create, the first JSON string does not contain a member named `apple`. In the second row, the string does contain a member `apple` but the value is `null`. The first query I show (looking for all JSON with an `apple` member) will include this row in the output. The last query is what you need: it adds a filter so that a JSON string must include at least one `apple` member with non-`null` value (regardless of whether it also includes other members named `apple`, possibly with `null` value).

```
create table sample_data
( id      number primary key
, colname clob   check (colname is json)
);

insert into sample_data
    values (101, '{name:"Chen", age:83, values:["{apple:6}", "street"]}');

insert into sample_data
    values (102, '{data: {fruits: [{orange:33}, {apple:null}, {plum:44}]}}');
    
insert into sample_data
    values (103, '[{po:3, "prods":[{"apple":4}, {"banana":null}]},
                   {po:4, "prods":null}]');
```

Note that I intentionally mixed together quoted and unquoted member names, to verify that the queries below work correctly in all cases. (Remember also that member names in JSON are **case sensitive**, even in Oracle!)

```
select id
from   sample_data
where  json_exists(colname, '$..apple')
;


 ID
---
102
103
```

This is the query you need. Notice the `..` in the path (meaning - find an object member named `apple` *anywhere* in the JSON) and the filter at the end.

```
select id
from   sample_data
where  json_exists(colname, '$..apple?(@ != null)')
;

 ID
---
103
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp_like function for this:
where regexp_like(colName,'apple : [0-9]')

Comment: It will skip `{"apple":10}` which is the same as `{apple:10}` and will return positive false for `{"someKey": "apple : 1"}`. No need to reinvent JSON processor if it is already there.

Comment: with json.regexp_like i get error stating the function is not available.